# weird edges with no vertices

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

theres these weird points between to vertices that my image object keeps running into and i cant figure out how to fix them, pressing "J" brings up an error and splitting the face only makes it worse.

[image: error]

[image]

Comment: Maybe mark on screenshot what part exactly you have in mind and also consider uploading .blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Sometimes edges look like this when having a subdivision surface modifier active...

Comment: okay, cool thanks, is there anyway to change them from being a hard edge to a curve?